# How to use inventory data on a single host in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I get my network inventory for `ansible` dynamicly from the `netbox` plugin and I want to use this data to edit the /etc/hosts file and run a script on a special host (librenms) to add all the network devices there.

Has anyone an idea how to run a playbook only on the librenms host with the data of the netbox inventory plugin?

Here my inventory (the librenms host is not part of it)

```
plugin: netbox
api_endpoint: https://netbox.mydomain.com
token: abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz
validate_certs: False
config_context: True
group_by:
  - device_roles
query_filters:
  - role: test-switch
  - has_primary_ip: True
```

Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Either target your play to `hosts: librenms` or limit a wider playbook to that host with the `-l librenms` option. But very basically => `ansible-playbook -i yourinventory [-l librenms] your_playbook.yml`

Comment: Hi Zeitounator, thanks for your answer. The problem is, that the librenms host is not part of the dynamic inventory. These are only switches. I get the following error:
`ERROR! Specified hosts and/or --limit does not match any hosts`

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#using-multiple-inventory-sources

Answer (score 1):

If the host you want to run the playbook on is not part of your dynamic inventory and at the same time you want to use variables defined in the dynamic inventory in a play for that host, you have to construct an "hybrid" inventory containing both your dynamic inventory ans other static entries.

This is covered in the documentation on inventories: [Using multiple inventory sources](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#using-multiple-inventory-sources).

Very basically you have two solutions:

- Use two different inventories on the command line:

  ```sh
  ansible-playbook -i dynamic_inventory -i static_inventory your_playbook.yml
  ```
- Create a compound inventory with different sources in a directory. See chapter "Aggregating inventory sources with a directory" in the above documentation.